# Extract Fields in a CLOB using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I'm seeking help to extract the fields "before" and "after" (with the related values)  in this CLOB saved in a table using PL/SQL.

{ "sorted": { "dragId": "7839", "dropId": "7782" }, "sequence": { "before": [ "7839", "7782", "7698" ], "after": [ "7782", "7839", "7698" ] }}

Non sure if it is probably not formatted well but after some research and trying I am not able to extract them. Can someone help me? Really appreciated

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? You have provided an example of the CLOB data you are trying to read, but an example of the results you are trying to extract would help, specially the format of the result you are trying to extract: sequences separated or just the sequences before and after without dividing the different sequence values? Do you need dradId?

Comment: Hi Ana, thanks for your help...yes sorry maybe I have not been more precise... What I am looking to do is to store the sequences values "before" and "after" dividing the single values... I am using a plugin in Apex ( Drag and Drop ) and I need to store in the DB those values before/after performed Drag and Drop....not sure how can I do that...

Comment: So, in your example, you want to present two tables in APEX, one for before sequences, another for after sequences. Before table will have in your example 3 rows with values "7839", "7782", "7698", and after table will have another 3 rows with values "7782", "7839", "7698"

Comment: as a starting example... yes :)

Comment: What version of oracle is this ? There a many native json functions that can be used to extract data

Comment: the oracle version is 19c

Answer (score 1):

Use function JSON_TABLE with clause NESTED:

```
select * from json_table('{ "sorted": { "dragId": "7839", "dropId": "7782" }, "sequence": { "before": [ "7839", "7782", "7698" ], "after": [ "7782", "7839", "7698" ] }}
' columns (nested path '$.sequence.before[*]' columns (vals_before varchar2(100) path '$'),
nested path '$.sequence.after[*]' columns (vals_after varchar2(100) path '$'))
)
```

Returns:

7839    null

7782    null

7698    null

null    7782

null    7839

null    7698